# pytest: Mock returning a mock with specific properties

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, magicmock

I found I often use same pattern in tests again and again:

```
mock_get_data = mock.MagicMock()
mock_get_data.get_data.return_value = "mocked DB data"
mock_db = mock.Mock(spec=DBClass, return_value=mock_get_data)
```

It would be used for testing (with patching) that type of code:

```
db_connector = DBClass(settings)
print db_connector.get_data()
```

Is any way to make that 'double mock' thing shorter?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
mock_db = mock.Mock(spec=DBClass, return_value=mock.Mock(get_data=lambda:"mocked DB data"))
```

Comment: Is any way to do it without double mock.Mock creation?

Comment: You can pass any other object, For example configure class it in the fixtures and pass it like a return_value, but i think that Mock is the more proper way

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by passing in a dictionary to the constructor, as described in the [configure mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.configure_mock) section of the docs, instead of configuring it after the MagicMock is created.

I believe the following would achieve the desired result:

```
mock_db = mock.Mock(spec=DBClass, return_value=mock.MagicMock(**{"get_data.return_value": "mocked DB data"})
```